# Prevent Text Overflow by Inserting Breaklines

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

A question... How can we insert breaks into string and make a multi line string to prevent overflow in axis lengths of an fixed width element?!

Exapmple Code that include the problem:

```
<div style="width:100px;">
    Too Long String...
</div>
```

I need to be like this one:

```
<div style="width:100px;">
    Too Long String (Line 1st)<br />
    Too Long String (Line 2nd)<br />
    Too Long String (Line 3rd)<br />
    Too Long String (Line 4th)<br />
    ...
</div>
```

What kind of client side script should i use for ?!

Comment: The text in a fixed-width `<div>` will line-break on its own in the browser. If it does not line-break for you, your question is not complete.

Comment: A picture for understand the problem : http://www.4ul.com/uploads/Capture[1].JPG

Comment: Just put spaces in your string (as shown in the pic, there is none), normaly the breaks will occur automatically

Comment: i put the complete code at some posts later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the style property "**word-wrap: break-word**" u will get a multi lined string without overflow.

regards

Comment: You are welcome. why don't u mark it as answer for ur question?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the system alot.. I did

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<div style="width: 100px; word-break: break-all;">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Comment: Please read w3 specs: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp. It's not Firefox NOR Opera compatible

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your requirement. If using your code, the long text will show as multi-line text and it won't overflow horizontally by default.

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD**

The way I would fix this is by putting a p tag within your div and style is so that it has a width, is floated and has display set to block, this should fix your problem, and this does not include any jQuery so it will reduce client load times.

**EXAMPLE:**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>
        Too Long String... Too Long String... Too Long String... Too Long String... Too Long String... Too Long String... Too Long String... Too Long String... Too Long String... 
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    background-color:#000000;
}
.container p {
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    display:block;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/8WP4J/

**Source:**

General knowledge from using HTML and CSS for similar problems

Hope this helps, any issues, feel free to comment.

Comment: @Memphis Just updated the anser with a slight modification and a JSFiddle, it works unless you have a long string that has no spaces in it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you all code...

The HTML Code:

```
<table class="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td><div>Header Codes ans CSS Comes Here</div></td>
        <td><p>Too Long String...</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And The CSS Code:

```
.tbl {
    table-layout:fixed;
    width: 568px;
}
.tbl td {
    border:1px solid #C93;
}
```

The result is something like this : http://www.4ul.com/uploads/Capture[1].JPG
And our too long string go out of the table width (if we set size for the p tag, nothing will changes...)